# How to repeat a function with the values returned by the function itself?

Tags: python, function, repeat

I have this function which returns two values and I want to repeat the same with those returned values.

```
fPoint = getFirstPoint (x, y, currCalcX, currCalcY) 
newCurrValX, newCurrValY = fPoint
print(newCurrValX, newCurrValY)
```

Above function returns values like this:

```
250.0 60.0
```

I want to apply these values on currCalcX and currCalcY and repeat the function `getFirstPoint()` until `None` is returned.

Comment: You need recursion, refer:https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/recursion

Comment: Okay, I will look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
# dummy implementation - returns None if a or b is 0, ignores x and y
def getFirstPoint(x,y,a,b):
    if a==0 or b==0:
        return None
    return a-1,b-1

x, y, currCalcX, currCalcY = 0,0,4,4  # add sensible values here

while True:
    fPoint = getFirstPoint (x, y, currCalcX, currCalcY) 
    if fPoint is None:
        print("Done")
        break
    currCalcX, currCalcY = fPoint
    print(currCalcX, currCalcY)
```

Output:

```
3 3
2 2
1 1
0 0
Done
```

Recursion is not needed here - it stacks up on function stack frames needlessly. You might hit the recursion limit if it takes too many recursions (and it is not needed at all) - see [What is the maximum recursion depth in Python, and how to increase it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it) for recursion limit explanations.

Comment: Thanks, Let me try this.

Comment: Not working. I'm getting same values over and over. Seems function is not running with updated values.

Comment: @ShyamMohan fixed typo - you need to replace the values of `currCalcX, currCalcY` with the results - not create  `newCalcX, newCalcY`

Comment: That gives an error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'currCalcX' referenced before assignment
`

Comment: @Shy fully running example edited. The error you get in your code is probably because you did not set `'currCalcX'` before using in in the function